# How to choose project management applications?

Tags: pm-software, tools

How to choose project management applications? Is it the license, is it ergonomics, wealth of features, .etc?

Comment: If this is a shopping question, it will be closed as off-topic. On the other hand, if you want to know *how* to do a bake-off for your specific use case, you'll need to add a great deal of detail about your process, and what specific problem you're trying to solve for.

Comment: I see, the names of the companies I quoted sow doubt in you. Ok I will edit my question.

Comment: The requirements will be different for every organization.  Some organizations will be price sensitive, others are not, etc.  This remains a shopping oriented opinion related question.

Comment: You would choose your application based on the features that it offers that are most important to you and your organization. What are the requirements that you're looking for in terms of your software selection? What are the main things that your selection would need to do in order add value to your project management processes?

Comment: "Shopping questions" are always off-topic on PMSE. From the comments, it seems you want a canonical list of filtering criteria, but such a question is both too broad and ultimately too specific to your organization's needs to be answerable in our Q&A format. If you can edit the question to be less of a shopping question, it can be re-opened by the community.

Comment: @CodeGnome My question is about procurement management. I'all give more details

Comment: @JennieK_NS Thank you Jennie, Your approach of the meaning of the question is better. I think I'm not asking the question well. I will edit this question. The idea is, if the project manager is not limited by OPA (organizational process assets), and he is in the provisioning phase, we suppose  that he has the hand to choose his management tools. What will be the criteria of his choice of software, knowing that he must manage projects in Agile and others in Waterfall and that it is limited in funding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you would choose any tool.

Does it require licenses? Does your organisation already support one of these tools? 
Does it do what you want?  Jira is webbased distributed which is a huge plus. Do you need that?

Comment: Thank you that is what I want to know but also I would like to know more what gives more weight in terms of features ie the ability to support several types of projects, best practice (PMI, Agile .. .)

Answer (score 2):

- **[CodeGnome's Law](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/8974/4271)**

  > Define your process, *then* automate it.
- **CodeGnome's First Corollary**

  > If you can't do it by hand, then you can't automate it. Automation is a tool to increase consistency, but it is not in itself a substitute for a well-defined process or process control.

Comment: Okay, that's nice. But you do not answer my question

Comment: Here's the answer rephrased: What is it that you want to be able to accomplish, and do you know the method that you would accomplish this task manually if you needed to do so? If you have that, you can then find the tool that provides you with the same process but less work.

Comment: Jennie, Definitely, your reading is better. I now see the meaning of the question